# Is it possible to watch for changes in Config.groovy with watchedResources?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm developing a plugin in grails 2.0.1 where I want to monitor changes in the configuration of the application that's using it.

I tried to add this to my plugin definition file :

```
def watchedResources = ["file:./grails-app/conf/Config.groovy"]

def onChange = { event ->
    println " config has changed"       
}
```

Now every time I change anything in my application's Config.groovy, I'd expect to see that println statement output in my console, but I don't.

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong please (or if this is possible at all) ?

Thanks !

Philippe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to setup a watch for that, there's already one active. Use the `onConfigChange` event callback:

```
def onConfigChange = { event ->
  // TODO Implement code that is executed when the project configuration changes.
  // The event is the same as for 'onChange'.
}
```